# Titanium alloy : 'NSUnknownKeyException'?

Tags: titanium-alloy

Given ./views/listview.html such as :

```
<Alloy>
    <Window backgroundColor="white">
        <ListView id="listView" defaultItemTemplate="template">
            <Templates>
                <ItemTemplate name="template" id="template">
                    <Label bindId="name" id="title" />
                    <Label bindId="position" id="subtitle" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Templates>

            <ListSection id="listsection">
                <ListItem template="template" class=""/>
            </ListSection>  

        </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Given ./controllers/listview.js as :

```
var hrdata = [
  {"n":{"text":"Adrien"},"position":{"text":"Boss"}},
  {"n":{"text":"Alexandre"},"position":{"text":"Dev web"}},
  {"n":{"text":"Camille"},"position":{"text":"Graphiste"}}
];
var rows = [];
for (var i=0; i < hrdata.length; i++){
    var row = {
          'name' : { 'text' : hrdata[i].name },
          'position' : { 'text' : hrdata[i].position }
    };
    rows.push(row);           
};
$.listsection.setItems(rows);
```

I get the error :

```
[ERROR] :  The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'.
[ERROR] :  Reason:
[ERROR] :  [<NSConcreteValue 0x7a674520> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key text.
...
[ERROR] :  2015-12-16 09:13:44.686 hugoApp1[33611:1455573] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteValue 0x7a674520> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key text.'
...
```

I can't figure out what is my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ! The 'NSUnknownKeyException' is actually refering to my JSON's keys :

```
    var row = {
          'name' : { 'text' : hrdata[i].name },
          'position' : { 'text' : hrdata[i].position }
    };
```

`name` and/or `position` are conflicting with previously existing parameters. The data your provide via `$.listsection.setItems(rows)` is not pushed into an isolated and empty "custom data" box, but upon pre-existing box already owning a bunch properties. So you must **rename your keys** in the `./controllers/listview.js` and `./views/listview.html`.

```
    var row = {
          'hrname' : { 'text' : hrdata[i].name },
          'hrposition' : { 'text' : hrdata[i].position }
    };
```

views (partial) :

```
<ItemTemplate name="template" id="template">
    <Label bindId="hrname" id="title" />
    <Label bindId="hrposition" id="subtitle" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Tiny, not like some other frameworks, but it's it !